# app.set and app.engine in Express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, template-engine

I am following a [Node.js tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-express--net-33367).

Two lines for which I am not sure are:

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', hbs.__express);
```

I checked the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#app.set) for `app.set` and it only tells me:

> Assigns setting name to value.

But my question is what's the relevance of using this. I googled it and wherever `app.engine` is used `app.set` is called before.

Let me know the significance of using `app.set` before the `app.engine`.

**EDIT**

I found the following line, but I am still unclear as I am using template engine very first time:

> But we can tell Express to treat HTML files as dynamic by using the `view engine` directive, you see above.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The first line, `app.set` tells Express which template engine to use: In this case, `html`. This requires that there is a template engine installed with that name, and that this template engine feels responsible for files with the `.html` extension.

If you are using `ejs`, e.g., this single line is enough (although you usually also have a second call to `app.set` that defines the directory where to look for view files):

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Now, supposed you would like to use a template engine for *another* file extension, e.g. you would like the `ejs` engine not only to take care of `.ejs` files, but also of `.html` files.

In this case you can use the second line, which tells Express that for files with extension `html` you would like to call the `hbs.__express` function to render them (as there actually is no template engine called `html`). This essentially means that you want the `hbs` engine to render `.html` files.

The `__express` function is a de-facto standard for template engines under Node.js to be Express compatible: That's what their rendering function should be called so that Express can find it easily (if it has a different name, you can configure this as well, but that's a different story).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great answer just if you add that  `process.cwd() +/views`  is the default  directory  where to find the views. and for sure can be changed.